# Redirect from html link to IOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, tracking

I am new to IOS development.I want to know there is any way to redirect from normal html link(safari browser) eg `<a href="my sdk link">click here to download the awesome app</a>` to my `SDK` (here I want to find out IDFA for user tracking) and then redirect to my app download page in App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Add   SVWebViewController library,

#import in   SVWebViewController.h  where you want to open write code to open

```
SVWebViewController *webViewController = [[SVWebViewController alloc] initWithAddress:@"http://www.google.com"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```